# Data is not updating when the telerik report is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik-mvc

I am using telerik reporting and the report is not updating having some refreshing issues, after refreshing(refresh button on telerik template) it shows the updated data.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reportViewer1")
        .telerik_ReportViewer({

            serviceUrl: "/api/Reports",
            templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-8.2.14.1204.html',
            reportSource: {
                report: "@ViewBag.Report",
            },
            viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewModes.INTERACTIVE,
            scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,
            scale: 1.0,
            ready: function () {
                this.refreshReport();
            },

        });
});
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about those *refreshing issues* ? And why to refresh the report on the `ready` event?

Comment: Changes are not reflected on report until i click on refresh button.                 I m just trying to refresh the report at the time of loading report that's why  i m using  this.refreshReport()

Comment: But the report is loaded with the correct data at the beginning?

Comment: No it is not showing the correct data.. it is showing the data which is loaded previously and when i click on refresh button then it showing correct data.

Comment: Sorry, it is being hard to understand...

Comment: ok i am just trying to say that first time i click on report then it shows correct then i am doing changes in database then that changes are not reflect to the report and after that  i click on refresh button then it showing the correct data...

Comment: Oh I see. The refresh button exists because it doesn't updated automatically, indeed. Imagine how much it would overload your database updating a report automatically? Isn't a best practice. For that, you can create a Panel with a refresh timer, it would be better.